Mocking useRouter from next/navigation (App Router) in Cypress
I'm trying to test my component in cypress. the component uses the useRouter hook from next/navigation in a button to push back to another page.
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { VStack, Heading, Text, Button, Box, HStack } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const ForgotPassword = () => {
  const [usersEmails, setUsersEmails] = useState<String[]>([]);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);


  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEmails = async () => {
      const { error, data } = await supabase.from("users").select("email");

      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        const emailArray = data.map((user) => user.email);
        setUsersEmails(emailArray);
      }
    };

    fetchEmails();
  }, [supabase]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

  };

  return (
    <HStack h="100vh">
    <Box>

    <VStack w="full" maxW="md">
      <Heading as="h3" size="lg" color="#006bb2" alignSelf="flex-start">
        Forgot Password
      </Heading>
      <Text mb="15px">
        Enter your email and we&#34;ll send a link to reset your password
      </Text>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="example@email.com"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        {error && (
          <Text mt="5px" color="red">
            We cannot find your email
          </Text>
        )}

        <button>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>

      <Button
        leftIcon={<ArrowBackIcon />}
        color="gray.500"
        _hover={{ color: "#006bb2", cursor: "pointer" }}
        variant="link"
        onClick={() => router.push("/login")}
      >
        Back to Login
      </Button>
    </VStack>
    </Box>
    </HStack>

  );
};

export default ForgotPassword;


when i mount the component, i get the error from cypress

(uncaught exception)Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted


The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.
invariant expected app router to be mounted

but if i comment out the "import useRouter", "const router = useRouter()" line and remove the "router.push("/login")", then the component mounts and cypress doesnt throw any error
i've tried the next/router & next/link solution from cypress docs
import React from 'react'
import ForgotPassword from './page'
import Router from 'next/router'


describe('Testing the forgot password component', () => {
  context('stubbing out `useRouter` hook', () => {
    let router
    
    beforeEach(() => {
      router = {
        push: cy.stub().as('router:push')
      }

      cy.stub(Router, 'useRouter').returns(router)
    })

    it('checks if user email exits in db', () => {
      cy.mount(<ForgotPassword />)

      cy.get('input[name="email"]').type("johndoe@example.com");

      // cy.get('button').click()

      // cy.get('@routerBack').should((mock) => {
      //   expect(mock).to.have.been.calledOnce
      // })
    })
  })

})

cypress still throws the same "(uncaught exception)Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted" error and the component still doesn't mount.
i changed the line import Router from 'next/router' to import Router from 'next/navigation' and cypress error changes to

Trying to stub property 'useRouter' of undefined


Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: stubbing out useRouter hook


The uncaught exception Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted can be resolved by wrapping the component in <AppRouterContext.Provider value={router}>.
That's the major fix, but there's also some secondary ones:

The 'next/router' is used in the test, but "next/navigation" in the component. These should be the same router in both places.



To stub useRouter from the Router object, you need to name the default import
with: import * as Router from "next/navigation"
not : import Router from "next/navigation"
This solves the error Trying to stub property 'useRouter' of undefined




the alias used in the calledOnce assertion should be the same name as used in the stub.


Here is my test for the NextJs sample component
component
'use client'
 
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
 
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push('/dashboard')}>
      Dashboard
    </button>
  )
}

test
import React from 'react'
import { AppRouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/app-router-context.shared-runtime'
import * as Router from "next/navigation";
import Page from './example-client-component.js'

it('stubs the router', () => {
  const router = {
    push: cy.stub().as('router:push')
  }
  cy.stub(Router, 'useRouter').returns(router)

  cy.mount(
    <AppRouterContext.Provider value={router}>
      <Page />
    </AppRouterContext.Provider>
  )

  cy.get('button').click()

  cy.get('@router:push').should((mock) => {
    expect(mock).to.have.been.calledOnce
  })
})

test log

